# is there any way to change Facebook cover photo or profile picture from the API (Via my c# app)?

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-8, facebook-c#-sdk

I know that this question was raised out several times,
and I even read most of the questions regarding the topic.
But there was a gap of about a month till now, and I'd like to know if there is any process in changing the Timeline Cover picture from the api(via an app).
Do you know any new information about this?
Or is there a solution out there? (except for uploading to cover album or profile album)

c# code as example.. will be excellent

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

You can dynamically append the Profile user name and get it .

```
string ProfileURL = string.Empty;
ProfileURL = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + username +  "/picture";
```

Here username  will be your profile name.